# Dom element removal in Joomla causes Submit button non working. But clicking any other button submits form

Tags: jquery, dom, memory-leaks, joomla, formfield

I am creating a custom Joomla 2.5 formfield. This is intended to be shown in Administrator panel of Joomla.
This field allows the user to add as many options as they like. Each option is entered by the user in a separate text-box. Each text box is created dynamically (using jQuery) on click of a `(+)` button

`jQuery(lihtml).insertBefore( jQuery(plusbutton).closest('li') );`

where `lihtml` is the html code to insert.

And user can also remove any existing option by clicking `(-)` button

`jQuery(minusbutton).closest('li').remove();`

These all function works fine though after **removing** an option if we **add** some other option then everything goes great. But the following sequence causes problem:

`REMOVE-OPTION -> SAVE` option is removed, but save doesn't work
`REMOVE-OPTION -> SAVE -> ADD-OPTION` form is submitted and hence save method is called on click of a button.

I know that there is some conflict, may be with DOM, or jQuery memory leakage, but not sure.

I can see that `save` button updates the `task` field (*hidden*) with `customfield.apply` but actual submit is called only after clicking `(+)` button.

`NOTE:` Instead of SAVE, the same case also applies with any toolbar button in Joomla, like SAVE AS NEW, CANCEL etc.

Comment: without sourcecode or link it's very difficult to figure out, btw Joomla has also mootools wich (sometimes) conflict with jQuery, so try to disable mootools and check if the problem insists ...

Comment: I don't use `$` for jQuery so there is no problem of any such conflict. However the problem was solved with a simple modification.
I added `type="button"` to the `(+)` and `(-)` buttons and it works great.
This means `<button> </button>` buttons are by default of `type="submit"`